# Uniswap V3: quoteExactInputSingle throws an unexpected error for USDC-CVX but works fine for USDC-WETH

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, erc-20, uniswap

I am using [quoteExactInputSingle](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/periphery/lens/Quoter#quoteexactinputsingle) to get the exchange amount output for different tokens, the implementation works fine for USDC-WETH pair, but not for USDC and CVX pair.

When I am trying to get the exchange between USDC and CVX, it throws an error:

```
const amountOut = await quoterContract.callStatic.quoteExactInputSingle(
    '0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48',
    '0x4e3fbd56cd56c3e72c1403e103b45db9da5b9d2b',
    100,
    1_000_000,
    0
  );
```

But I get an error below:

```
{
  reason: 'Unexpected error',
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  method: 'quoteExactInputSingle(address,address,uint24,uint256,uint160)',
  data: '0x08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010556e6578706563746564206572726f7200000000000000000000000000000000',
  errorArgs: [ 'Unexpected error' ],
  errorName: 'Error',
  errorSignature: 'Error(string)',
  address: '0xb27308f9F90D607463bb33eA1BeBb41C27CE5AB6',
  args: [
    '0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48',
    '0x4e3fbd56cd56c3e72c1403e103b45db9da5b9d2b',
    100,
    '1000000',
    0
  ],
  transaction: {
    data: '0xf7729d43000000000000000000000000a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb480000000000000000000000004e3fbd56cd56c3e72c1403e103b45db9da5b9d2b000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f42400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    to: '0xb27308f9F90D607463bb33eA1BeBb41C27CE5AB6'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple problems with your parametrs:

1. The CVX token address `0x4e3fbd56cd56c3e72c1403e103b45db9da5b9d2b` is formatted in all lower case. Typically when working with Web3 addresses, you need to supply them in the checksum format, such as: `0x4e3FBD56CD56c3e72c1403e103b45Db9da5B9D2B`.
2. You're using `100` fee tier (0.01% swap fees) for the USDC/CVX swaps. Only a few 0.01% pools exist, and most likely the USDC/CVX pool is not created yet. Select another fee tier and check that such as pool exists.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was using this pool as my target, https://info.uniswap.org/home#/pools/0x0eff06710d737c7548c8177ba42e3abdcf3477a7. And I saw there was 'Remove CVX and USDC' in the transaction details. Does it mean this pool is dead? In this case, is there a way to find a pool still alive?

Comment: @NeoLiu The pool is always alive if it is initialized, so that's not an issue. A potential problem is that it has zero balance according to Etherscan (the Uniswap UI TVL is buggy, don't trust it): https://etherscan.io/address/0x0eff06710d737c7548c8177ba42e3abdcf3477a7